# Can Mac App Store purchased apps install Quicklook Plugins?

Tags: mac-appstore, quicklook-plugin, sandbox

Since all apps are now sandboxed when purchased from the Mac App Store, what does this mean for the install process? Do you literally downoad the `.app` bundle, which gets placed into `/Applications`, and then the process is complete?

Is it possible for an application that is sandboxed to install a Quicklook Plugin for use with filetypes it supports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, any application placed in the Applications folder can provide QuickLook support.

Sandboxing does not affect an application's ability to support QuickLook.

Mac OS X looks [inside applications for a QuickLook plug-ins folder](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Articles/QLArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005020-CH4-SW4). The specific folder is:

```
MyApp.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/
```

Support for Automator and Spotlight can also be provided using this per-application Library folder mechanism.

When you download an application from the Mac App Store you are still going through `/usr/bin/installer`. The Mac App Store downloads a flat-file installer package `.pkg` and then installs it on your behalf.

This allows the installation process to be more than just a single copy for complex applications; functionality that is only available to Apple software. For now, third party software can do no more than provide a single application to be placed within the /Applications folder.

Comment: Ah, I would have expected that it would only look in `/Library/QuickLook`, but looking in that directory I see fewer QLGenerators than I know I have on my system.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can add a Quicklook Plugin to an application. For example, QuickNFO uses one: [QuickNFO Mac App store page](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/quicknfo/id412843352?mt=12)